# Use insertbefore() after checking the duplicacy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using insertbefore() function in JS:

```
$('<div class="col-lg-3" ></div>').insertBefore("div.col-lg-9.col-md-9.col-sm-9.col-xs-12");
```

But what issue I am facing when there is already exists that particular div div col-lg-3 before "div.col-lg-9.col-md-9.col-sm-9.col-xs-12" after that its always perform insertbefore.

I want to check duplicacy and if already its present before same div then avoid insertbefore in that condition on a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** to loop and use **[`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)** function to get the element before and check if it is `div.col-lg-3` using **[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)**.

```
$("div.col-lg-9.col-md-9.col-sm-9.col-xs-12").each(function(){
    if( !$(this).prev().is("div.col-lg-3") )
        $('<div class="col-lg-3" ></div>').insertBefore(this);
});
```